# ¿Puedo compartir un programa de Python (3.x) con alguien que no lo tenga instalado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi primer lenguaje fue [c](/questions/tagged/c) y como pueden imaginar las diferencias con [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) son notables. Python es orientado a objetos y una diferencia importante para un novato en Python como su servidor es que mientras C es compilado, Python es interpretado.

Cuando aprendí C compartía mis programas sencillos (ya compilados) por diversión (algunos sí que les eran útiles), pero con Python quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de que alguien que no tiene instalado el intérprete pueda usar el programa de mi código python, pregunto porque además de la extensión **.py** noté que existen otras, no sé si esas ayuden.

P.D. Uso [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) OS.

Comment: En Linux las distribuciones ya vienen con Python, en Windows es necesario instalar el interprete para ejecutar los archivos con extensión .py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso de las distribuciones Linux la mayoria trae instalado python 2.7x, para el caso de windows puedes usar una herramienta como [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) que te crea un .exe de tu script y lo puedes compartir y lo pueden ejecutar sin tener python instalado.

Uso básico de PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed mi_script.py
```